# Ubuntu unable to boot with PCI Bus error and kernel panic not syncing unable to mount root fs

Tags: boot, kernel, mount

Hi my desktop Ubuntu unable to boot with message such as PCI error and Kernel panic unable to mount root fs on unknown block etc.
The full message is in the image as attached at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZrRH.jpg)
I have no idea what's happening. It doesn't fit other questions on the forum that have kernel panic as a result of upgrading Ubuntu.

Comment: For what it is worth; This might be a hardware problem with a severity that stops any(?) OS from booting - Suggestion: try downloading / acquiring 'Ubuntu install media' (e.g. ISO onto a USB-stick) and boot it in "Try Ubuntu"-mode - if that works, then see if you can find ways to use it to analyze and remedy the problem.